# Получить данные из связанных таблиц rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Поля таблицы City

```
create_table "cities", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "name"
```

Поля таблицы Order

```
create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "count"
t.integer "first_city_id"
```

Модель Order

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :city, inverse_of: :city
end
```

Модель City

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :orders, inverse_of: :order
end
```

Рабочий вывод данных из Order во view

```
<% @order.each do |orders| %>
<p> <%= orders.count %> </p>
<% end %>
```

Метод в контроллере

```
def edit
@orders= Order.all
@order=Order.where(:user_id == current_user)
end
```

Как получить значение name из таблицы Сity, если first_city_id в таблице Order содержит id нужной записи из таблицы City

Comment: А у вас `belongs_to :city` вообще работает? `city_id` в этой таблице я не вижу.

Comment: я написал не полный перечень полей, есть first_city_id и last_city_id, которые хранят id из таблицы city или он обязательно требует явного city_id и что тогда делать если мне дважды нужно сохранять id в разных полях?

Comment: Нужно более подробно и внятно изложить вопрос. Совершенно непонятно что есть и что нужно. Рискну предположить что нужно что-то типа `City.find(order.first_city_id)`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky В  таблице order содержится поле `first_city_id`, которое хранит id таблицы city. Нужно получить доступ к полям таблицы city с указанным id в `first_city_id`.

Comment: @anoam `curent_user.orders` работает и я могу получать записи полей таблицы `orders`, но когда пишу `City.find(order.first_city_id)` выдает ошибку _undefined local variable or method `orders` for..._ **не знаю как получить связанные данные**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный ответ на мой вопрос можно посмотреть на англоязычной версии : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614560/get-data-from-related-tables-rails?noredirect=1#comment60826048_36614560 автор Sibevin Wang

You should setup the order associations as follows:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :first_city, class_name: "City" # it would use first_city_id as the foreign key by default to access city table
  belongs_to :last_city, class_name: "City"
end
```

Getting the first/last city name from an order becomes easy:

```
@order = Order.first

@order.first_city.name
@order.last_city.name
```

If you want to get the first/last city name from an order list, you should use includes or joins to avoid the n+1 query:

```
@orders = Order.includes(:first_city, :last_city)

<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <p> First City: <%= order.first_city.name %> </p>
  <p> Last City: <%= order.last_city.name %> </p>
<% end %>
```

or

```
@orders = Order.
  joins("LEFT JOIN cities AS first_cities ON first_cities.id = orders.first_city_id").
  joins("LEFT JOIN cities AS last_cities ON last_cities.id = orders.last_city_id").
  select("orders.*, first_cities.name AS first_city_name, last_cities.name AS last_city_name")

<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <p> First City: <%= order.first_city_name %> </p>
  <p> Last City: <%= order.last_city_name %> </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Неплохо, осталось перевести :)